# use ! in Reactjs Component in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change `Material-UI` `Button` component.

```
<Button>
```

to

```
<Button disabled>
```

So my source code is this,but it shows the `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."`

```
<Button {!this.state.enClick ? "" : disabled }><Button>
```

Not in `Button` tag `{!A ? B:C }` works.

```
<Button>
{!this.state.enClick ? "OK":"No"}
</Button>
```

What is the best practice for this purpose??

Comment: this.state.enClick ? "No": "Ok"
That does the same

Comment: Your tag not closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
<Button disabled>
```

is short for this:

```
<Button disabled={true}>
```

The curly brackets pop you back into plain javascript, and you can put any javascript expression in there. Assuming `this.state.enClick` is a boolean, you can conditionally set `disabled` like this:

```
<Button disabled={this.state.enClick}>
```